# Representing the DNA alphabet in C with typedef and enum

Tags: c, dna-sequence, genetics

I'm writing a program that processes genetic sequence and I want to store each nucleotide in a byte where each bit represents one of the letters of the genetic alphabet `A,C,G,T` (only half of the bits will be used evidently).

My encoding is the following:

```
A = 0b1000
C = 0b0100
G = 0b0010
T = 0b0001
R = 0b1010
Y = 0b0101
N = 0b0000
```

Here, `R` are purines, which can stand for `A` or `G`, `Y` are pyrimidines (`C` or `T`), and `N` could stand for either letter.

What is the best way to define this format in C using `typedef` and `enum`? I would like to define a type that allows me to assign a letter to a variable by name such as

```
typedef ... nucleotide_t;
nucleotide_t x[] = {G, A, T, T, A, C, A};
```

Edit: Thanks for the input. I definitely have my reason for not wanting strings, but thanks for the suggestion. It's true that logically, `N` should be `0b1111` but for my application it does make more sense to represent it as *none of the above*.

Please note that I *do* have an idea how to make this work, but I don't break out the ol' C too often and I'm rather looking for what the most elegant solution is. I guess if I want to reserve the `NUL` byte, then I could just add `0b10000` to my code everywhere.

I think the two possible ways to go are either an `enum` or some `#define` macros. Yet, enums are `int` and I need a `char`, so are macros the better solution?

Comment: Perhaps you could use something like `#define A (0b1000)` or `#define A (0x8)`. Share and enjoy.

Comment: +1 for the title - reminds me of old 19th century British travelogue's such as "Across Africa With Cannon And Butterfly Net".

Comment: Unless this kind of encoding greatly improves performance, I would just use ASCII characters. That way you can use `strstr` and similar functions that work on null-terminated strings. If you do need the bit patterns to have special meaning, you might at least avoid using the value 0 so that you can still use string functions on your sequences.

Comment: Seems to me that if R=A|G and Y=C|T, and if N is a wildcard, it should be R|Y, or `1111` binary, unless you really mean for it to be "none of the above". Although, @R.. is certainly correct that you won't get much help from standard C string functions, you'll at least be able to write your own match function using logical operators, and if you don't use `0` as a code, you could conceivably use something like C-style NUL-terminated sequences if that's convenient.

Answer (score -1):

How about do it this way:

```
typedef enum NUC{
   N            = 0,
   T            = 1,
   G            = 2,
   C            = 4,
   Y            = 5,
   A            = 8,
   R            = 10
}nucleotide_t;
```

Comment: Then why not just omit them?

Comment: This would create an `int`, not a `char`.